# Problema no nome da tabela durante a criação pelo hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou “anotando” uma entidade `Menu` usando o hibernate/jpa, e `Menu` contém uma entidade `ShareActivity` *embeddeble* que eu criei.

```
@Entity(name="menu")
public class Menu implements Component { 
    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name="menu_share_activity",joinTable=@JoinTable(name="share_activity"))
    private ShareActivity enable;
    ...
    getters e setters
}
```

interface Component é vazia

```
@Embeddable
public class ShareActivity {

    @NotNull
    @CollectionTable(name = "share_activity")
    private Map<Actor, Boolean> status;

    public ShareActivity() {
        this.status = new HashMap<Actor, Boolean>();
        this.status.put(Actor.owner, true);
        this.status.put(Actor.company, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.custumers, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.employee, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.friend, false);
    }
    ...
    getters e setters
}
```

fasso uso de um enumerador para restringir o número de atores no meu map

```
public enum Actor {
    owner,
    friend,
    custumers,
    company,
    employee
}
```

Em fim quando eu adiciono a variável `ShareActivity` na minha classe `Menu` ela cria uma tabela `Menu_status`, só que `Menu` está “anotado” como `@Entity(name="menu")` e ainda assim a tabela enciste em criar o nome da classe `Menu` com m maiúsculo, já tentei `@Table(name="menu")`, e não funcionou.

Alguém sabe se da pra fazer isso, e se sabe como faz?

Meio que todo o banco de dados está sob o padrão ***snake_case***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a anotação `@AssociationOverride`. Exemplo:

Classe `Menu`:

```
@Entity
public class Menu { 

    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(name="status",joinTable=@JoinTable(name="menu_share_activity"))
    private ShareActivity enable;

    //outros métodos e atributos 
}
```

Classe `ShareActivity`:

```
@Embeddable
public class ShareActivity {

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="actor")
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="value")
    private Map<Actor, Boolean> status;

    public ShareActivity() {
        this.status = new HashMap<Actor, Boolean>();
        this.status.put(Actor.owner, true);
        this.status.put(Actor.company, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.custumers, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.employee, false);
        this.status.put(Actor.friend, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: dessa forma cria apenas uma tabela, e impossíbilita o reaproveitamento em outras classes (esqueci de mencionar o map em B está anotado como ElementCollection e ele por padrão nomeia como classe_variavel a tabela, e como é Embedebla esse elementCollection deveria fazer a_s) uma vez que A está com Entity(name="a")

Comment: @bruno_arabica editei a resposta com uma solução para esse caso.

Comment: estou recebendo esse erro: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: A, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(s)].                                                             
e a anotação @CollectionTable não está criando a tabela

Comment: @bruno_arabica você terá que editar sua resposta e colocar as classes A, B, C e D correspondentes do seu projeto. Sem saber como elas são, não é possível te ajudar.

Comment: Editado! As classes são javabeans, por conta disso removi os outros atributos e os métodos pôs eles não são tão importantes para a pergunta

Comment: @bruno_arabica editei a resposta com a solução.

Comment: fincionou perfeitamente, agradecido por toda ajuda